# How to use Structr platform to add a new node to an existing relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, structr

I am new to Neo4j and I want to add a new node to an existing relationship using Structr platform.

This is the Cypher query that I tested in Neo4j web browser and it works.

```
match(projects:Project {name:'IRIS Recognition Java'}) 
create(client:Client {name:'Andreas Pal'}) CREATE(projects)-[w:IS_PART_OF]->(client)
return w
```

In the Structr platform I created a table that contains all the existing projects from database and I want to assign a member to the project. 
 I tried to put in a table date a query to bring also the clients. And I don't know how to create the assign. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Structr's means of editing the data in the database. If you use Cypher directly, you are modifying the data on a different (wrong) level. You can either use Structr directly to create relationships, or you have to make the relationships in a way that Structr can detect and "see" those relationships.

Please have a look at https:/support.structr.com/article/295 for more information.

Comment: Can you give me please an example of how you do this, like steps that can be followed? Thank you.